# Why do some projects that use typescript/webpack also use babel to finish compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2, babeljs

I've noticed some web projects using typescript and webpack also use babel to finish off the compilation. For example, they use ts to compile to ES2015 and then use babel to compile to es5. Why not just use ts directly to compile to es5?

Is it in the case the project also has js that needs to be compiled so they just use babel for everything? Or what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few possible reasons for this.

1. **They're using Babel to automatically polyfill** - TypeScript only performs syntactic transformations, leaving the user to figure out what runtime libraries they'll need to be around (e.g. `Promise`, `Symbol`, etc). This allows you to decide which implementation of these polyfills will work the best for you, but it can be a pain. Babel spares you the burden of thinking about that. It's a tradeoff.
2. **They need it for a custom transformation** - TypeScript has a transform pipeline, but it's only accessible when you use the TypeScript API at this point in time. If you're already using Babel and want to start using TypeScript, but you're already using a transform, this is a reasonable compromise.
3. **It was created when TypeScript didn't support compiling generators to ES5 (or even back when TypeScript didn't support `async`/`await` in ES5)** - TypeScript has supported `async`/`await` in ES5 since 2.1, and has supported generators behind the `downlevelIteration` flag since 2.3. Before that, users often relied on Babel to pick up the slack, but Babel isn't needed here anymore.
4. **It was created before Webpack 2 and the project used a specific way of importing modules** - TypeScript has an `allowSyntheticDefaultImport` option which tells TypeScript that default imports can be used to import certain modules. Babel supports this behavior, but Webpack didn't until Webpack 2 came out. Babel isn't needed here anymore for newer versions of Webpack.

This might not be the complete set of reasons, but it's a few I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

> Why not just use ts directly to compile to es5?

That is what I do.

## About mixing Babel and TypeScript

There is no flaw in using the both together. Since both do:

```
 (non js OR js) => standard js
```

You can do

```
 (non js OR js) => standard js => es5
```

Either by `TS -> JS -babel> ES5` or `Babel -> JS -ts> ES5`

The reason people do it is for varied syntax support : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/

## Personally

As mentioned. I don't use Babel [as I TypeSafety is big for me and don't need to use syntax that isn't yet type safe](https://medium.com/@basarat/typescript-won-a4e0dfde4b08)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is the evolution frOM ES2016 onwards. Typescript helps the developer from c# and java background to become javascript developers using various tools. Visual Studio code, WebStorm, Sublime etc.

**Why: We can not use Typescript alone for converting ts to ES5**
  Compiling to ES5 with TypeScript is not as complete as it is with Babel. Some modern language features, such as Array.prototype.find, cannot be compiled to ES5 with TypeScript.

Here is the link that will help you out: https://www.stackchief.com/blog/TypeScript%20or%20Babel%3F